# ASP.NET - can a hidden/invisible control fire a change event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**EDIT:** I found a workaround - I use a `HiddenField` instead of a `TextBox`, and in the jQuery, after setting the `HiddenField`'s value, I do a `__postback` on the parent `UpdatePanel`, then handle the `HiddenField`'s value in the `Page_PreRender`.

I have an ASP.NET page that calls a jQuery `confirm()` that, if accepted, should fire an event in the underlying code without doing a full `PostBack`. What I currently do is, I have an ASP.NET `TextBox` with `AutoPostBack=true` inside of an `UpdatePanel`, and on the confirm, I change the TextBox's text and then trigger its `OnTextChanged` event with `.trigger('change')`.

This works - **if** the `TextBox` is visible. If it is hidden, which is what I want (I don't want the user to see, much less be able to edit, the value), then the `TextBox` is undefined in the page (the client doesn't bother creating it).

I have tried using an `ASP:HiddenField`, but there is no `AutoPostBack` for it.

Here is the code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="PageVariablesPanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="EditsMade" AutoPostBack="true" Text="0" OnTextChanged="EditsMade_TextChanged" />                   
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmTheChange() {
        if (confirm("Do you want to confirm the change?")) {
            $("#<%= EditsMade.ClientID %>").val("1").trigger('change');
        }
    }
</script>
```

As I said, when the user clicks on "OK" on the confirm, it does change EditsMade to 1 and then fires EditsMade_TextChanged; however, if I set the EditsMade visible property to false, EditsMade.ClientID returns "undefined."

Is there a way to get JQuery to fire an event based on a hidden TextBox or HiddenField without doing an full PostBack?

Comment: If this "visible" property is server-side then it probably isn't sending non-visible controls to the client at all.  Have you checked the resulting client-side code (in the page source or browser's debugging tools) to see if your `EditsMade` element exists on the page?

Comment: As an aside... *"I don't want the user to see, much less be able to edit, the value"* - If the value is client-side and being posted to the server then the user **can** see and edit the value.  From the description it sounds like you're trying to achieve two mutually exclusive things, allowing the client to update a value without allowing the client to update the value.

Comment: When you put it that way, it makes sense. I think I found a way around it; see my edited question.

Comment: Regarding the update, it's still worth noting (for you and/or future readers) that the workaround *does not* satisfy the requirement of *"I don't want the user to see, much less be able to edit, the value"*.  Anything that comes from the client is visible to and editable by the user.

Comment: I think that what the server side code supposed to do will much define how you should approach this code.  See my code below,  but since the update panel does nothing more than send that one value then a web method on that page probably makes more sense. So what does the code behind do with this one simple value?

Answer (score 0):

As noted, any control set with visible = false means that markup is NOT sent nor rendered to the client side.

So, and it not clear at all that how a text changed event for a text box would EVER fire since you saying that the user NEVER edits that text box anyway? that does not make ANY sense at all here?

Since the text box is assumed to not be visible, then how on earth is the text changed event of that text box going to fire?

So, don't try and make some "on text changed" event to then be used to trigger the update panel. If you goal is to trigger the up-date panel, drop in a button to the UP, and click on that. So, move your code behind event stub to the button in that UP (and hide the button).

So, your code behind stub now is the button click.

A air code "proof of concept" would thus look like this:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="EditsMade" runat="server"
                  Value="0"
                  ClientIDMode="Static"/>

                <asp:Button ID="cmdUPPost" runat="server" Text=""  ClientIDMode="Static"
                    OnClick="cmdUPPost_Click"
                    style="display:none"  />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


        <script>

            function confirmTheChange() {
                if (confirm("Do you want to confirm the change?")) {
                    $('#EditsMade').val("1")
                    $('#cmdUPPost').click()
                 }
             }
        </script>
```

So, you modify the hidden field, and then click on a button (hidden) in the update panel, and that will do the partial page post-back. Do keep in mind that while a UP looks like it not doing a post-back, the page life cycle, including that of the page load event does fire when that UP does post-back.

So, we can't use visible = false for the hidden button, since as noted, any control with visible = false means the asp.net engine does NOT send that markup to the client side.

And really, to JUST send one value back to the server? It is a bit of a overkill to drop in a update panel, and click a button. Probably less effort to just use a jQuery.Ajax call, and tag the code behind on that page as a webMethod.

However, for now, the above proof of concept should suffice.